# Visual Studio C++ data structure errors, "link1120"

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors

I'm new in data structure, right now i'm working on a assignment and don't know what is the problem with this structures. Please need help. I will post  a image of these errors.

[image]

I don't know what these errors means. What I have to do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// Estructura para tipos de persona.
struct persona {
string nombre;
string direccion;
int numero;
};
persona proveedores[];
persona clientes[];
persona empleados[];

// Estructura para producto.
struct producto {
string nombre;
int numero;
};
producto product[];

// Indice para variables de estructura... para referencia
int NUM_Proveedores,
NUM_Clientes,
NUM_Empleados,
NUM_Producto;

void menuPrincipal() {
cout << "Bienvenido a Apple Inc.\n"
    << "MENU: Que deseas hacer?\n"
    << "1. Entrar Data.\n"
    << "2. Ver data.\n"
    << "3. Salir del programa.\n";
}

void menuData() {
cout << "Bienvenido a Apple Inc.\n"
    << "MENU: Entrada de datos.\n"
    << "1. Entrar Proveedores.\n"
    << "2. Entrar Clientes.\n"
    << "3. Entrar Empleados."
    << "4. Entrar Productos.\n"
    << "5. Salir del programa.\n";
}

int main(){
int choise_MenuPrincipal;
int choise_MenuData;

menuPrincipal();  // call menuPrincipal function
cin >> choise_MenuPrincipal;

if (choise_MenuPrincipal == 1) {
    menuData();
    cin >> choise_MenuData;

    if (choise_MenuData == 1) {
        // Proveedores code here
        cout << "Cuantidad de proveedores a ingresar: ";
        cin >> NUM_Proveedores;
        // loop de proveedores
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_Proveedores; i++) {
            cout << "Nombre del proveedor " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> proveedores[i].nombre;

            cout << "Direccion del proveedor " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> proveedores[i].direccion;

            cout << "Numero del proveedor " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> proveedores[i].numero;
        }
    }
    else if (choise_MenuData == 2) {
        // Clientes code here
        cout << "Cuantidad de clientes a ingresar: ";
        cin >> NUM_Clientes;
        // loop de clientes
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_Clientes; i++) {
            cout << "Nombre del cliente " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> clientes[i].nombre;

            cout << "Direccion del cliente " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> clientes[i].direccion;

            cout << "Numero del cliente " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> clientes[i].numero;
        }
    }
    else if (choise_MenuData == 3) {
        // Empleados code here
        cout << "Cantidad de empleados a ingresar: ";
        cin >> NUM_Empleados;
        // loop de clientes
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_Empleados; i++) {
            cout << "Nombre del empleado " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> empleados[i].nombre;

            cout << "Direccion del empleado " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> empleados[i].direccion;

            cout << "Numero del empleado " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> empleados[i].numero;
        }
    }
    else if (choise_MenuData == 4) {
        // Producto code here
        cout << "Cantidad de productos a ingresar: ";
        cin >> NUM_Producto;
        // loop de producto
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_Producto; i++) {
            cout << "Nombre del producto " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> product[i].nombre;

            cout << "Numero del producto " << i++ << ": ";
            cin >> product[i].numero;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "End Program." << endl;
    }

}
else if (choise_MenuPrincipal == 2){
    // ver data code here
}
else {
    cout << "End Program." << endl;
}


system("Pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You should post the error text as text verbatim into your question please, the text in the image is very hard to read (too small).

Comment: Next time include the minimal example please. There's a lot of code you could remove and still keep the question clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you can't define array like this

```
persona proveedores[];
```

The compiler needs to know the size of the array in advance. One solution is change this line to

```
const size_t MAX_SIZE = 100;
persona proveedores[MAX_SIZE];
```

...and then do the same with `clientes`, `empleados`, `product` etc.

If you need dynamic size array, use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have not allocated memory for your structures.

```
persona proveedores[];
persona clientes[];
persona empleados[];
```

Later on you are trying to access something you don't have really
    cin >> proveedores[i].nombre;

Please allocate your arrays like

```
persona proveedores[10];
persona clientes[10];
persona empleados[10];
```

and you'll get rid of compilation issues at least.